# Netbeans 8 UML Diagrams

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram, netbeans-8

How to generate class diagrams of a project with Netbeans 8.x?

I tried to install the UML plugin from http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/m1/dev/catalog.xml but this corrupted the whole settings of NB.

It should be possible to create a class diagram by right clicking on a project / file and say create class diagram or similar to the ObjectAid plugin for Eclipse. Preferably open-source; must be free

Answer (score 8):

Tools -> Plugins > Look for "PlantUML". Install that. Then you're good to go! (:

Comment: 2½ years i can't seem to find the plugin inside netbeans but, As this seems old, it's available for NB 8.0 here => http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49069/plantuml